# Why is eslint throwing incorrect syntax error on module export file?

Tags: javascript, reactjs, module, react-router

I'm using the [react-router auth example](https://github.com/ReactTraining/react-router/blob/master/examples/auth-with-shared-root/utils/auth.js) to implement a login flow. In the setup I added the `auth.js` file to my utils folder. The file is using module.exports to allow it to be invoked from other files.

But when I build the solution it breaks on this file, telling me that:
 `Message:
    Missing semicolon.
    Details:
    fileName: src\js\util\auth.js
    lineNumber: 3`

So I added the semicolon to the line 3, `cb = arguments[arguments.length - 1];` 
which then throws a subsequent ESLINT error telling me a semicolon is expected after this line `if (cb) cb(true)` which doesn't seem correct.

Question:

Why is ESLINT throwing incorrect syntax error on a valid module export file?

The auth.js file is detailed below as taken from the react-router example:

```
module.exports = {
  login(email, pass, cb) {
    cb = arguments[arguments.length - 1]
    if (localStorage.token) {
      if (cb) cb(true)
      this.onChange(true)
      return
    }
    pretendRequest(email, pass, (res) => {
      if (res.authenticated) {
        localStorage.token = res.token
        if (cb) cb(true)
        this.onChange(true)
      } else {
        if (cb) cb(false)
        this.onChange(false)
      }
    })
  },

  getToken: function () {
    return localStorage.token
  },

  logout: function (cb) {
    delete localStorage.token
    if (cb) cb()
    this.onChange(false)
  },

  loggedIn: function () {
    return !!localStorage.token
  },

  onChange: function () {}
}

function pretendRequest(email, pass, cb) {
  setTimeout(() => {
    if (email === 'joe@example.com' && pass === 'password1') {
      cb({
        authenticated: true,
        token: Math.random().toString(36).substring(7)
      })
    } else {
      cb({ authenticated: false })
    }
  }, 0)
}
```

Answer (score 0, accepted):

JavaScript will accept your code, even if it's missing semicolons at the end of each statement, but ESLint has apparently been configured not to. A lot of people prefer to put semicolons at the end of each statement, but if that's not your style, you need to tell ESLint. There's simply a mismatch between your coding style, and ESlint's coding style.

If you want to disable checking of semicolons completely, add the rule `"semi": 0` to your .eslintrc.js file:

```js
{
  "rules": {
    "semi": 0
  }
}
```

ESLint is completely configurable, and you can find a list of all of the rules you can enable or disable yourself [here](http://eslint.org/docs/rules/).

Comment: that makes sense so I added in the rule and it got rid of the semicolon errors. But even after adding a newline at the end of the file by returning to a newline at the end of the file and saving. I get ` Newline required at end of file but not found.
Details:
    fileName: src\js\util\auth.js
    lineNumber: 49
`

Comment: @BrianJ That's the [`eol-last`](http://eslint.org/docs/rules/eol-last) rule. It sounds like there's a lot of rules that have been misconfigured; you should go through them one by one, and as long as they're not actual errors, you can safely disable or change them.

Answer (score 0):

This is because of the new ES6 feature [Object literal shorthand](https://ariya.io/2013/02/es6-and-object-literal-property-value-shorthand). Try the following.

```
module.exports = {
  login: function login(email, pass,cb){ //need to give a name to the function, else, eslint will throw an error
   ...
  }
}
```

Comment: Same as below I changed the method def to `login: function login(email, pass, cb) {` and same error about missing semicolon line 3. Put a semicolon online 3 and got the same error about missing semicolon on line 5

Answer (score -1):

I guess you are doing the object-key mapping wrong. Try this:

```
 login: function(email, pass, cb) {
    cb = arguments[arguments.length - 1]
    if (localStorage.token) {
      if (cb) cb(true)
      this.onChange(true)
      return
    }
    pretendRequest(email, pass, (res) => {
      if (res.authenticated) {
        localStorage.token = res.token
        if (cb) cb(true)
        this.onChange(true)
      } else {
        if (cb) cb(false)
        this.onChange(false)
      }
    })
  },
```

Comment: ok did try that but..got the same error about missing semicolon line 3. Put a semicolon online 3 and got the same error about missing semiclon on line 5..Any other ideas?